# How to add multiple series to wpf chart using MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I can do this for single series according to [this article](http://65.39.148.34/KB/WPF/WPFChartingMVVM.aspx).

but I could t do it for multiple series. If some one knows a way please help me..

Comment: The "this article" link is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://bkiener.wordpress.com/2010/02/07/databinding-multi-series-charts/

This is the one that I use in my WPF/MVVM application.  It too, was written for Silverlight, but it works for WPF as well.  In fact, it looks the same as the example that @anivas provided, but I prefer this one as it describes the implementation better.

Comment: can you provide the code you use for the WPF case as I can seem to get it working using the WeakReferences in the Silverlight example...

Comment: The blog link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

WPF chart doesn't support dynamic binding of series collection. You can easily achieve this using an attached property. This is an [example](http://jmorrill.hjtcentral.com/Home/tabid/428/EntryId/351/Silverlight-Charts-Binding-multiple-Series.aspx) in `Silverlight` but you can use it in `WPF` as well.

Comment: +1 for supplying a link that hasn't broken over the past 2 years.